# Move highcharts legend outside of chart container

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to move highcharts legend to outside of charts container, When I have surfed for the options I got this link https://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/legend-placement-outside-of-chart-area-t28582/, Is is possible to make a legend on callback, Or any other options to move the legend outside?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with just few CSS these parameters `legend.x` and `legend.y` - [API Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.x)

CSS

```
body{
  background-color:#ddd;
  padding:100px;
}
.highcharts-container, .highcharts-container > svg{
  overflow:visible !important;
}
```

Javascript

```
...

legend:{
    verticalAlign:'top',
    x:-300,
    y:-100
},
...
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5b04nqgc/)

Comment: I don't find the legend container anywhere in that fiddle

Comment: @Aarthi, It was under the chart now I updated the fiddle to show it above the chart

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chart.events.load` event function to create the legend after chart loading. It shouldn't be problematic, but here is a little prototype, which shows how it could be achieved:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
 chart: {
   events: {
     load() {
       var seriesOneBtn = document.getElementById('s1')
        var seriesTwoBtn = document.getElementById('s2')
       var chart = this
        var seriesOne = chart.series[0]
        var seriesTwo = chart.series[1]
        
        seriesOneBtn.onclick = function() {
         seriesOne[seriesOne.visible ? 'hide' : 'show']()
        }
        seriesTwoBtn.onclick = function() {
         seriesTwo[seriesTwo.visible ? 'hide' : 'show']()
        }
        
      }
    }
  },
 legend: { 
   enabled: false
  },
 series: [{
   data: [1,2,3]
  }, {
   data: [3,2,1]
  }]
})
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

#legend {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid tomato
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="legend">
  <button id="s1">Series 1</button>
  <button id="s2">Series 2</button>
</div>
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Kind regards!

Comment: Is this for moving the legend outside or controlling series from outside?.

Comment: You cannot move legend outside, because it's a part of Highcharts, but you can define your own legend, which will have the same functionality as Highcharts one.